Fill the space with black, bounded by two arcs
I need to fill the space between the arcs with color
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Define radius and angle variables for both arcs
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radiusOne}{3.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startangleOne}{147}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\endangleOne}{33}
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radiusTwo}{4.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startangleTwo}{130}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\endangleTwo}{50}      
        
        % Set rounded ends for all lines within scope
        \begin{scope}[line cap=round, line width=2mm]
            % Vertical line
            \draw (0,0) -- (0,5);
            
            % Horizontal line
            \draw (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
            
            % Curved line (arc 1)
            \draw ({\radiusOne * cos(\startangleOne)}, {\radiusOne * sin(\startangleOne) - 1.5}) 
            arc[start angle=\startangleOne, end angle=\endangleOne, radius=\radiusOne];
            
            % Curved line (arc 2)
            \draw ({\radiusTwo * cos(\startangleTwo)}, {\radiusTwo * sin(\startangleTwo) - 3.0}) 
            arc[start angle=\startangleTwo, end angle=\endangleTwo, radius=\radiusTwo];
        \end{scope}
        
        % Fill the space between the arcs
    %   \begin{scope}
            % Set black fill color
    %       \fill[black] 
    %       arc[start angle=\endangleOne, end angle=\startangleOne, radius=\radiusOne]--
    %       arc[start angle=\endangleTwo, end angle=\startangleTwo, radius=\radiusTwo];
    %   \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}



Off-topic: The coordinate ({\radiusOne * cos(\startangleOne)}, {\radiusOne * sin(\startangleOne) - 1.5} can simply be written as ([shift=(down:1.5)]\startangleOne:radiusOne) or, with the calc library loaded, as ($(\startangleOne:\radiusOne)+(0,-1.5)$).

We merge your two draw commands into a single path (this means swapping startangle and endangle for the second one), and fill it (I used blue so you can see the fill, but of course you can use black):
\draw[fill=blue] ({\radiusOne * cos(\startangleOne)}, {\radiusOne * sin(\startangleOne) - 1.5}) 
            arc[start angle=\startangleOne, end angle=\endangleOne, radius=\radiusOne]
                    % Curved line (arc 2)
            %\draw
         %   ({\radiusTwo * cos(\endangleTwo)}, {\radiusTwo * sin(\endangleTwo) - 3.0}) 
            arc[start angle=\endangleTwo, end angle=\startangleTwo, radius=\radiusTwo];


